# Formula for a sequence for 9*9 grid

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any possible formula which creates numbers in sequence of 0,1,2,10,11,12,18,19,20. It's a 9*9 grid which consist 9 subgrids of 3*3 matrix.

Comment: I don't see how nine numbers could be a "$9\times 9$ grid".  Of course there is some formula...label your numbers $a_i$ for $i\in \{0,8\}$ and then define $a_j=a_i$ if $j\equiv i\pmod 9$.  That defines a periodic sequence beginning with your list.  Or you can find a polynomial with $p(i)=a_i$.  Not knowing where this sequence came from, there's really nothing more to do with it.  For what it's worth, I agree that there is no apparent trivial pattern (linear or whatever).

Comment: i am creating Sudoku  , in each subgroup there can be only one number from 1-9.  So domain is 1-9 while index is 0-80.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that relates to your question.  I thought you were asking "is there some convenient formula for $a_i$ which matches these particular nine numbers for $i\in \{0,\cdots, 8\}$?"  I gave a couple of examples...the first is convenient enough (but it's likely that it isn't what you want) and the second is likely to be a polynomial of degree $8$ so not all that convenient.  If you want the formula to have special properties, you need to tell us what they are.

Comment: I computed the interpolating polynomial (well, I asked wolfram alpha to compute it for me).   It is $$-x^8/960 + (37 x^7)/840 - (1063 x^6)/1440 + (127 x^5)/20 - (86507 x^4)/2880 + (3073 x^3)/40 - (68561 x^2)/720 + (4597 x)/105$$  I think my "inconvenient" prediction stands.